# Reading one file, parsing, and writing another

Tags: c, file-io

Consider the file,

```
L,12/5/2008,Blacktown
C,Willy Wonker,10.00
C,Adolph Hitler,20.00
C,Attila the Hun,30.00
C,Idi Amin,40.00
C,Ghengis Khan,50.00
T,150.00
L,13/5/2008,Parramatta
C,Attila the Hun,100.10
C,Willy Wonker,200.20
C,Ghengis Khan,300.30
T,600.60
L,14/5/2008,Mount Druitt
C,Adolph Hitler,1000.00
T,2000.00
L,15/5/2008,Penrith
T,0.00
L,16/5/2008,Chatswood
C,Ghengis Khan,1.00
C,Idi Amin,10.00
C,Adolph Hitler,100.00
C,Attila the Hun,1000.00
T,1111.00
```

I need to write a program that opens the file `Collections.txt`, reads it and formats it in the given order, and writes it to another file called `Reports.txt`.  I need to have the `date`, a `tab`, and then the `name`.  Then a new line and the `names`, a `tab`, and the `amount`.  Repeat until a `T` is detected; this signals we have no more collections for the above location.  Then rinse and repeat for every location until it reaches the end of the file and a final total must be displayed.

Here is the code I have written,

```
/*
This program collects data and writes it to a specific file.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void debt_calculator();
void main()
{

    printf("This is a debt collection program:\n ");
    debt_calculator();
    scanf("%*c");
}

void debt_calculator()
{
    char code;
    int date [40];
    char location [40];
    char name [40];
    float amount = 0;
    float total = 0;
    float grand_total;
    int ctr = 0;

    FILE * Collections;
    Collections=fopen("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Assignment2\\Assignment2\\Collections.txt","r");
    if(Collections==NULL)
    {
        printf("file not open:\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE * Report;
    if((Report=fopen("C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\Assignment2\\Assignment2\\Report.txt","w"))==NULL)
    {
        printf("can not open file: \n");
        exit(1);
    }


    fscanf(Collections,"%c,",&code);

    while(code == 'L')
    {
        fscanf(Collections,"%[^,],%s%*c",date,location);
        fprintf(Report,"Date: %s \t Location: %s \n\n",date, location);
        fscanf(Collections,"%c,",&code); 
    }

    for(code == 'C'; ctr < 5; ctr++)
    {
        fscanf(Collections,"%[^,], %f %*c",name, & amount);
        if(amount == 0)
        {
            fprintf(Report,"### No Collections for %s \n", location);
            fprintf(Report,"total: \t 0.00\n");
        }

        fprintf(Report,"\n Name: %s \t Amount: %.2f \n",name, amount);
        fscanf(Collections,"%c,",&code);
    }

    code == 'T';
    while(code == 'T')
    {
        fprintf(Report,"Hello");
        fscanf(Collections,"%f",& amount);
        total += amount;
        grand_total += total;
        fprintf(Report,"Total: \t %.2f \n",& total);
        fprintf(Report,"Grand Total of all Collections is: $ %.2f", grand_total);
        fscanf(Collections,"%c" , & code);
    }

    fclose(Collections);
    fclose(Report);
}
```

When I run the above program it displays the `printf()` statement and when I hit enter and it exits.  Than I open my `report.txt` file and find the date tab location new line and all the names and costs up until the `T`.  Once it gets to the 'T' it stops, I cant get it to go into the last while loop, read the total and print it to the file than repeat by checking the code again.  The code after the `T` is a `L` so it should go back into the first while loop and read than write the date and location but it does not.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Also if there's any better way you think I should be doing this please let me know.

Comment: I don't see any C++ in there. Changed tag to C.

Comment: Debugger. Do you use it?

Comment: @Jonathan: ["The homework tag...is now discouraged,"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/10812) but, @Nick, please (as always) follow [general guidelines](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints): state any special restrictions, show what you've tried so far, and ask about what specifically is confusing you.

Comment: @Billy: I think that was caused by entering "visual c++" in the tags for the IDE he's using (i.e. note the original title).

Comment: @Roger Thanks, I hadn't been aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tries stepping in the debugger and observing the variable state while doing so?

This line:

```
fprintf(Report,"Total: \t %.2f \n",& total);
```

is certainly incorrect, %f does not expect a pointer.

If the expectation is that `code == 'T';` will force it to enter the loop, you are mistaken, `code = 'T';` would work.

Similarly in this loop:

```
for(code == 'C'; ctr < 5; ctr++)
```

The initialising expression shpuld be `code = 'C'`

Try setting your compiler warning level to \W4 and \Wx (all warnings are errors), then the compiler may help you spot such errors.

Comment: +1, and I'd suggest that putting `code = 'C'` in the initialisation part of a loop when it is not in the test part is loop abuse.

Comment: Hi.For the for loop thats a typo i realize why it should be one = instead of 2.
But for the while loop it should be 2 not one should it not?
because one = is saying the variable is this, where 2 is saying is the variable this.
thats what i need to check, i cant say code = 'T' because that would be a automatic fail because i am not reading the file, im telling the program what it should do when it should be the one figuring out that to do.

I think what our teacher wants us to do is use a switch case statement for each case.
Would that be a good idea?
If so how would i implement it?

Comment: Yes i have tried the debugger, our teacher always tells us to ignore warnings because the compiler gives us stupid warnings like telling us to use gets when im storing a char not a string.

Comment: @Nick: That is very poor advice from your teacher, and suggests that he has poor knowledge of programming; those warnings are the compiler helping you find bugs, even when they are benign, they should be fixed if only so you can see the wood for the trees and not miss real semantic errors .  I doubt the compiler gave any such warning as "use gets when storing a char not a string".  You should never use gets() in any case!

Comment: @Nick:  I was referring to the line of code immediately *before* the while loop; i.e. the line of code I reproduced!

Comment: All that is for is to write the floating point number i read above.
I implemented that poorly, i should of written amount to the file than assigned it to total, instead of the other way around.

Problem i am having is i can not understand why it is not going into the last while loop.
I think its the implementation, its not going into the loop at all because if i go into the loop and first line put a printf in there the printf never gets executed, that tells me we are never entering the loop for some reason.

Would i be better off using a switch case statement for each of the location codes?

Comment: @Nick:  I *told* you, it never enters the loop because `code` is not initially equal to 'T' because the line where you appear to be pre-setting it is incorrect; it is a boolean expression *not* an assignment.  Your compiler should be issuing a "statement with no effect" warning or similar.  Rather that presetting it, you could use a do-while loop instead.

Comment: Its not initially equal to T but by the time it gets to the third while loop code should be T after reading the file.
There in that code above im even assigning the code T so it should be entering the loop, but its not.
I cant do a do while loop because that is assuming there is a T and my teacher will fail me on this exercise because were suppose to read the file, we cant assume anything.
I will have to get rid of that for loop too, that is also assuming and ill fail if i leave that there.

Im going to try a switch case see how that goes, its due tomorrow so im really running out of time.

Comment: @Nick:  I am not sure how many ways I can explain this:  `code == 'T';` **is not** an assignment!  Either way, that is probably irellevant.  You need to *iteratively* read *a whole line*, then switch of the value of the first character, and in the individual cases process the rest of the line.  The solution is *far simpler* than your current implementation.  You are making it too hard.

Comment: How can i make it simpler?
Played around with step into and out debug features last night, turns out code is always 'L' or 'C' as far as the compiler is concerned.
It is never 'T' so that tells me for some reason its reading every line, than once it hits the last C line it stops when it should keep going.
I know code == 'T' is not a assignment, its checking to see if code really is equal to T.
Only one = sign would be a assignment.

Comment: @Nick: "its checking to see if code really is equal to T" - no it is not, it *is* a boolean expression, but nothing is checking its result.  The while loop does that in any case.  That line is entirely redundant.  With regard to making it simpler, I think I answered that, but if I get time, I'll elaborate with an example.